# Can python variables be assigned by digits?

Tags: python

There's this guy here who insists that python variables can be assigned like

```
1 = 'foo'
```

I need help on what to tell him.

Comment: tell him to try it. and it wont work...problem solved

Comment: Tell him to prove it

Comment: Imagine, for a moment, that you could do that. You would have then broken the number 1. Now you can't add 1 to anything, because 1 equals `'foo'`. You can't set anything equal to 1. What happens if you want to do a `range()` starting at 1? You'd now be starting from `'foo'`, which makes no sense. In reality, Python will not allow this, and even if it did, for the love of all that is sacred, no one should ever do such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

No.

- A variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character.
- A variable name cannot start with a number. A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (`A-z`, `0-9`, and `_` )

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp

Answer (score 2):

**No it cannot haha.** 
the simplest way to tell him is to show it.

if you run the code

```
1 = 'foo'
```

then you will get an error message, that will help him understand.

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You get a syntax error.

Also, per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names):

> Function and Variable Names
>
> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the
>   prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards
>   compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible.

Name of variable in python should not be started with any number.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. See [illegal variable names](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use digits as the first character of a name. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers